# Recycling materials like plexiglass, polycarbonate and dibond

Tags: materials, recycling

I'm working on a project for a printing company with the main goal to reduce their waste. Paper products are not the issue but they also use materials like plexiglass, polycarbonate and dibond.

I was wondering if it is at all possible to recycle those materials and how. And if not, what happens with them?